# Enter Key not working on submit button Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is the submit button:

```
 <input type="submit" ng-click="Showdata()"  class="btn blue pull-right" Text="" />
```

Here is the text box for email:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="texttype" class="form-control" ng-class="eml" placeholder="Enter Email" />
```

here is the textbox for pass:

```
  <input type="password" ng-model="passwordtype" class="form-control" ng-class="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" />
```

Here submit working for the mouse click..But how can i work on enter click??
Here i am using angularjs.
How can i submit on both mouse click and enter key press?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: You can Also refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs

Comment: use ng-submit instead of  ng-click or change type submit to button

Comment: Please refer below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs

Comment: ng-submit same problem

Comment: any solution please write on the answer

Comment: Here is the Good explanation for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417125/submit-form-on-pressing-enter-with-angularjs

Comment: still not working

Comment: Go to your form and insert this code `<form ng-submit=" " name="logform" method=" ">`  . After you enter the data, on submit of enter your data will be posted.

Comment: I have created Plunker check it out : https://plnkr.co/edit/s9eE25TN4cKkmCcWHdzg?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ng-enter` directive. I think this will help you.

```js
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []).filter('moment', function() {
    return function(dateString, format) {
        return moment(dateString).format(format);
    };
});

app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
 
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.DoWork = function(){
          alert('Hello World! ' + $scope.MyText);  
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input ng-enter="DoWork()" ng-model="MyText" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: It is working somehow but when the text box having null value it is not hit the button

Comment: in other case what is happening for you?

Comment: <span id="errorUserName" style="color: Red;"></span>

Comment: there is the validation if no value then this span becomes true

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `form` tag with `ng-submit`

```
<form name="sampleForm" ng-submit="Showdata()">

  <input type="text" ng-model="texttype" class="form-control" ng-class="eml" placeholder="Enter Email" />    
  <input type="password" ng-model="passwordtype" class="form-control" ng-class="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" />
  <input type="submit"  class="btn blue pull-right" Text="" />   

</form>
```

Comment: Its not working..my form structure is just like this..but not working

Comment: @asasasaa check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248651/angular-ng-submit-enter-key-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Add one class named like "**searchTextbox**" in input field
And then use that code

```
    $('.searchTextbox').keypress(function (event) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    $scope.Showdata();
                }
            });


<input type="text" ng-model="texttype" class="form-control searchTextbox " ng-class="eml" placeholder="Enter Email" />
```

Comment: May be it's working for both mouse click and enter key.